# Trouble getting ```IF``` statement working to check records and provide error

Tags: mysql

I can't use a picture yet because I don't have enough reputation so ill just put the create table code

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    `code` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT credit_check CHECK (credits IN (50 , 75, 100)),
    CONSTRAINT pri_course PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
    CONSTRAINT uni_code UNIQUE (`name`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE module (
    `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    cost DECIMAL(8 , 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
    course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT uni_name UNIQUE (`name`),
    CONSTRAINT pri_module PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
    CONSTRAINT for_module FOREIGN KEY (course_code)
        REFERENCES course (`code`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT cred_check CHECK (credits IN (25 , 50))
);
```

```
INSERT INTO course (`code`, `name`, credits)
VALUES ('WSD', 'Web Systems & Development', 75);
INSERT INTO course (`code`, `name`, credits)  
    VALUES ('DDM', 'Database Design & Managment', 100);
INSERT INTO course (`code`, `name`, credits)
VALUES ('NSF', 'Network Security & Forensics', 75);
```

```
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('A2', 'ASP.NET', 250, 25, 'WSD');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('A3', 'PHP', 250, 25, 'WSD');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('A4', 'JavaFX', 350, 25, 'WSD');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('B2', 'Oracle', 750, 50, 'DDM');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('B3', 'SQLS', 750, 50, 'DDM');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('C2', 'Law', 250, 25, 'NSF');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('C3', 'Forensics', 350, 25, 'NSF');
INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code)
VALUES ('C4', 'Networks', 250, 25, 'NSF');
```

Above is the create table code and insert that I'm wanting to run an `IF` statement the `IF` statement will be inside a procedure which is going to take two input's and if they pass the statements they will be inserted, the inputs are to schedule new dates for courses. I'll put my code here...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE new_course (IN give_code CHAR(3), give_date DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE com_mod BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE new_code CHAR(2);
DECLARE loop_date DATE;
DECLARE new_course CHAR(3);
DECLARE mod_c CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `code` FROM module WHERE course_code = give_code;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET com_mod = TRUE;


    IF (give_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) OR (give_date <= CURDATE()) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Enter A Date Over One Month';
    ELSEIF (WEEKDAY(give_date) = 5 )THEN SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(give_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY);
    ELSEIF (WEEKDAY(give_date) = 6 )THEN SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(give_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    ELSE SET loop_date = give_date;
    END IF;
    
   IF give_code <> ANY ( SELECT code FROM course ) THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; 
END IF;
    
    OPEN mod_c;
    
    looper : LOOP
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM mod_c INTO new_code;
        IF com_mod THEN LEAVE looper;
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO `session` (`code`, `date`) 
                VALUES (new_code, loop_date);
            IF (WEEKDAY(loop_date = 5))
                THEN SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(loop_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY);
                ELSE SET loop_date = DATE_ADD(loop_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
            END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE mod_c;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the code that I can't figure out,

```
IF give_code <> ANY ( SELECT code FROM course ) THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please Check Entered Course And Try Again'; 
END IF;
```

I want it to only insert codes that are in the course table but I don't want to hard code them as I want the procedure to be future proof for when additional courses are added. Currently, it's giving the error for anything I try to insert

Comment: You cannot remove posts by editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change

```
IF give_code <> ANY ( SELECT code FROM course ) THEN
```

to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM course WHERE code = give_code) THEN
```

Comment: OMG that works... how did you figure that out so quickly??? what does the number 1 mean in this statement?

Comment: 1 just an constant (number), which is not used and relevant. The purpose is to check the condition is true or false. If it is true, it will return a resultset of 1. You can also add LIMIT 1.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain that more, so the number 1 is to act as true? so 0 would be false? what would be the difference in putting 2 or 3 and so on?

Comment: You can put anything (number/string constant, column names, *) there, it is irrelevant.  We just care it returns something (EXISTS) when the condition (in WHERE) is true. We do not use the returned value.